# Верстка: main и aside во всю высоту страницы

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, адаптивная-верстка

Подскажите, как растянуть блоки на всю высоту страницы?

[Пример на jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/ovSeo/xsh9ew97/)

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

p {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.6em;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

strong {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
}


/**********************************/

#wrapper {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header,
nav,
main,
footer {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #333;
  height: 100px;
}

nav {
  background-color: #262626;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  height: 70px;
}

main {
  padding: 40px;
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  ;
  column-count: 2;
  width: inherit;
}

aside {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  padding: 40px 20px;
  width: 300px;
  float: left;
}

#aside {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

footer {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 70px;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header></header>
  <nav></nav>

  <aside>
    <strong>The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s</strong>
    <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
      dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
  </aside>

  <main>
    <section>
      <h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>
      <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
        It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
        desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

      <h2>Where does it come from?</h2>
      <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked
        up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus
        Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from a
        line in section 1.10.32.</p>
      <p>The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English
        versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p>
    </section>
  </main>
  
  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

У тегов `header`, `nav` и `footer` фиксированная высота (из-за этого не получается нормально использовать `height: 100%`). Высота `aside` и `main` подстраивается под контент. Как сделать, чтобы высота обоих блоков была одинаковой?

Не хочется использовать JavaScript и всякие обманки (например, лишний `div` с `background-color` как у `aside`). Возможно сделать это средствами HTML+CSS?

Comment: Table не подходит, т.к. нужна адаптивная вёрстка.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нашёл решение. Это flexbox (`display: flex`). Работает во всех браузерах, кроме IE8-.

Мой исправленный и рабочий пример:

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

p {
  padding: 10px 0;
}

h1 {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.6em;
}

h2 {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 1.4em;
}

strong {
  font-weight: 600;
  font-size: 16px;
}


/**********************************/

#wrapper {
  max-width: 1400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

header,
nav,
main,
footer {
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  background-color: #333;
  height: 100px;
}

nav {
  background-color: #262626;
  border-top: 1px solid rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
  height: 70px;
}

main {
  background-color: #fff;
  height: 100%;
  ;
  /**/
  display: flex;
}

#Content {
  padding: 40px;
  column-count: 2;
  /**/
  flex-grow: 1;
}

aside {
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
  padding: 40px 20px;
  width: 300px;
  /**/
  flex-shrink: 0;
}

#aside {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: #f7f7f7;
}

footer {
  background-color: #333;
  height: 70px;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="wrapper">
  <header></header>
  <nav></nav>

  <main>
    <div id="Content">
      <section>
        <h1>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h1>
        <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
          It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with
          desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.</p>

        <h2>Where does it come from?</h2>
        <p>Contrary to popular belief, Lorem Ipsum is not simply random text. It has roots in a piece of classical Latin literature from 45 BC, making it over 2000 years old. Richard McClintock, a Latin professor at Hampden-Sydney College in Virginia, looked
          up one of the more obscure Latin words, consectetur, from a Lorem Ipsum passage, and going through the cites of the word in classical literature, discovered the undoubtable source. Lorem Ipsum comes from sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 of "de Finibus
          Bonorum et Malorum" (The Extremes of Good and Evil) by Cicero, written in 45 BC. This book is a treatise on the theory of ethics, very popular during the Renaissance. The first line of Lorem Ipsum, "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet..", comes from
          a line in section 1.10.32.</p>
        <p>The standard chunk of Lorem Ipsum used since the 1500s is reproduced below for those interested. Sections 1.10.32 and 1.10.33 from "de Finibus Bonorum et Malorum" by Cicero are also reproduced in their exact original form, accompanied by English
          versions from the 1914 translation by H. Rackham.</p>

        <h2>Why do we use it?</h2>
        <p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout. The point of using Lorem Ipsum is that it has a more-or-less normal distribution of letters, as opposed to using 'Content
          here, content here', making it look like readable English. Many desktop publishing packages and web page editors now use Lorem Ipsum as their default model text, and a search for 'lorem ipsum' will uncover many web sites still in their infancy.
          Various versions have evolved over the years, sometimes by accident, sometimes on purpose (injected humour and the like).</p>

        <h2>Where can I get some?</h2>
        <p>There are many variations of passages of Lorem Ipsum available, but the majority have suffered alteration in some form, by injected humour, or randomised words which don't look even slightly believable. If you are going to use a passage of Lorem
          Ipsum, you need to be sure there isn't anything embarrassing hidden in the middle of text. All the Lorem Ipsum generators on the Internet tend to repeat predefined chunks as necessary, making this the first true generator on the Internet. It
          uses a dictionary of over 200 Latin words, combined with a handful of model sentence structures, to generate Lorem Ipsum which looks reasonable. The generated Lorem Ipsum is therefore always free from repetition, injected humour, or non-characteristic
          words etc.</p>
      </section>
    </div>

    <aside>
      <strong>The standard Lorem Ipsum passage, used since the 1500s</strong>
      <p>"Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure
        dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum."</p>
    </aside>
  </main>

  <footer></footer>
</div>
```

[Пример с jsfiddle.net](https://jsfiddle.net/ovSeo/m36rfc9u/)

Что нужно сделать написано здесь (вкратце):
[Скажите «Привет, flexbox»](http://webformyself.com/samyj-legkij-sposob-sozdat-bokovye-kolonki-odinakovoj-vysoty/)

На Хабре подробно расписано, что такое flexbox и как его использовать (2014 год):

[Практическое применение flexbox](https://habrahabr.ru/post/242545/)

Про баги кроссбраузерности flexbox (2015 год):

[Упорядочивание багов кроссбраузерности flexbox](http://css-live.ru/articles/uporyadochivanie-bagov-krossbrauzernosti-flexbox.html)

Ещё про использование flexbox и его кроссбраузерность (2014 год):

[Равномерное выравнивание блоков по ширине](http://css-live.ru/articles-css/progressive-flexbox-horizontal-justify.html)